# Зачем используют указатели в качестве членов класса?

Tags: c++, указатели

ключевая фраза вопроса ниже, для отличия от других подобных вопросов:
каковы критерии выбора использовать член класса как статичный объект или как указатель?

---

В книгах по c++ слабо освещается (либо я плохо искал) тема причин для использования указателей. объекты размещаются в стеке, а создавая объект через new он создается в куче, что дает нам больше памяти для использования. в части массивов это укладывается в голове. а как дела обстоят с классами ?
пример класса

```
class A
{
 std::string name;
 std::string group;

 ClassB*  class_b;
 std::vector<ClassC> vector;
};
```

что должно стать критерием использования вместо std::string  указателя на std::string ? или указателя на std::vector ?
периодически вижу в чужом коде  указатели на строки, но вектора идут обычно как статичные объекты.

Comment: Я за свои ~9 лет работы с C++ ни разу не видел указателей на `std::string`, а если бы увидел, то попросил бы весомых аргументов, почему человек так сделал. Я вряд ли их получил бы.

Comment: возможно плохой пример. вместо него обычно идут самописные классы для хранения строк. либо из внешних библиотек icu.UnicodeString

Comment: Просто строка это уже указатель, в большинстве случаев, не понимаю зачем можно хранить указатель на строковый класс.

Answer (score 3):

Причин может быть много. К примеру, у нас может быть класс дерево или односвязный(двусвязный) список. Тогда, в первом случае мы храним указатель на родителя и список [умных] указателей на детей. В случае списка мы храним указатели на соседний(соседние) элементы.

Другой пример, внедрение зависимостей(dependendecy injection) — в классе мы храним указатель на интерфейс, который инициализируем конкретным классом в какой-то части программы. Так, в классе мы храним обобщённый указатель, который уже внешняя сущность инициализирует конкретной сущностью.

Пример номер три, мы создаём какой-то класс, который должен хранить другие классы, но у него жёсткое ограничение по занимаемой памяти на стеке — поэтому вместо самих классов(больших) мы храним указатели на них(умные).

Пример номер четыре, так называемая pimpl идиома, когда все данные, которые хранятся в классе выносятся в отдельный приватный класс, а в публичный класс выносится указатель на этот класс(в целом, это частный случай примера 3). Это позволяет снизить время компиляции, за счёт снижения подключаемых заголовков в публичном классе. Очень активно этой идиомой пользуется Qt, весь фреймворк этим пронизан.

Это далеко не все примеры, до которых может дойти программист. Поэтому указатели довольно частые гости в членах класса.

Comment: да, эти примеры я понимаю. когда хранить нужно что то внешнее, или инициализируемое в "середине" работы, а может и не обращаемся к этому - тут лучше указатели. В большинстве других случаев ничего не мешает обойтись без них, так получается ?

Comment: @ctapmex, всё верно. Хотя, конечно, каждый случай стоит рассматривать отдельно, я мог что-то важное пропустить. Поэтому никаких аксиом тут нет — надо смотреть по ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Из личного опыта :) - в основном там, где существенную роль играет размер и наследование. Обойтись, конечно, можно почти всегда, но... и не всегда, и получится не очень.

Например, массив боооольших объектов. Сортируемый. При сортировке объекты надо обменивать местами, т.е. копировать большое количество памяти - если данные большие. Если в объекте хранить указатель на эти данные - то и обменивать придется только указатели.

Или представим класс с данными, которых становится все больше и больше (типа вектора). Т.е. надо выделять новую память. Как обойтись без указателей на эту вот выделяемую память?

Наследование - потому что, например, виртуальные функции работают через указатели или ссылки. Например,

```
Base * b;
b = new Derived();
b->virtualFunc();
```

То же можно делать со ссылками, но с ними часто гораздо неудобнее, потому что раз инициализированную ссылку изменить нельзя.

Примерно так...

Используя указатели, можно облегчить и обезопасить жизнь применением интеллектуальных указателей типа `unique_ptr` или `shared_ptr`, но это немного другая тема.

В качестве *личного мнения* - при наборе определенного опыта и использовании идиомы RAII - опасность указателей представляется мне сильно преувеличенной...

Comment: тут не страх использования указателей, тем более что есть умные указатели. скорее не понимание, зачем в некоторых случаях хранят в виде указателя то, что и так можно. и не очень большие знания по стеку/куче. я знаю что стек ограничен, размер задается при компиляции, и обычно он пара мегабайт.  
ситуация. есть класс , тот что в начальном примере.  я создаю динамически много объектов этого класса. тогда все статичные элементы создаются в выделенной мной под объект куске памяти, ведь так ?

Comment: @ctapmex Вот еще один пример, где спасают указатели - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497233/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-c

Answer (score 0):

Указатель используется для динамического создания объектов. Если он используется там, где можно обойтись стеком или ссылкой - то это не очень правильно и не оправданно.

Comment: из соседнего комментария -  есть класс , тот что в начальном примере. я создаю динамически много объектов этого класса. тогда все статичные элементы создаются в выделенной мной под объект куске памяти, ведь так ? не на стеке?

Comment: Да, все верно .

Comment: спасибо. это прояснило почти все.