# Как уменьшить зависимость заголовочных файлов C++?

Tags: c++, dll

Допустим есть файл A1.h с описанием класса A1 (`class A1 { ...};`), файл A2.h с описанием класса A2 (`class A2 {...};`). Есть файл B1.h, в котором подключаются заголовочные файлы A1.h и A2.h и описывается класс B1 (

```
#include "A1.h"
#include "A2.h"

class B1 {
A1* pA1;
A2* pA2;
...
};
```

). Как уменьшить зависимость заголовочных файлов, чтобы когда подключалась dll библиотека не нужно было тянуть за собой много заголовочных файлов ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере в файле B1.h нет необходимости подключать файлы A1.h и A2.h, так как описанный вами класс В1 содержит лишь указатели на классы А1 и А2. Достаточно будет предварительного объявления:

```
class A1;
class A2;

class B1
{
  A1* pA1;
  A2* pA2;
};
```

А заголовочные файлы А1.h и А2.h необходимо подключить в файле реализации B1.cpp.

Comment: И ещё совет: поищите информацию об использовании идиомы Pimpl.